# While running selenium script my csv download file script get skipped due to switch to other area

Tags: selenium, junit

Run the below script properly that time not moved any other area  but if perform any action I mean move to any other area that time my download file code not work.

Is the issue related to focus or need some changes. using firefox 21 version browser and selenium 2.33. Please suggest.

Here is the code:

```
package mypackage;

import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import Data.Function;
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.junit.After;

public class Report extends Function {

    Object Open_a_popup_window;
    String Positioned_Popup ;
    Object JavaScript_Popup_Windows ;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        baseUrl = "my url";
    }

    @Test
    public void Report1() throws Exception {
        Function object = new Function();
        object.Login();

        /* Enter Report Details */
        driver.get(baseUrl + "//");
        driver.get(baseUrl + "//");

        /*Run*/
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("")).click(); 
        Thread.sleep(30000);
        WebElement Action = driver.findElement(By.xpath(""));

        for (String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
            driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
            ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.focus();");}
            String linktxt = Action.getText();
            if (linktxt.equalsIgnoreCase("Record not found.")) {
                System.out.println("Report contains No Data:"); 
            }

            if (linktxt.equalsIgnoreCase("FAILED")) {
                System.out.println("Report failed");    
            } else {
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("/img")).click();

                Robot robot = new Robot();
                robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
                robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
                Thread.sleep(10000);

                robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
                robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
                Thread.sleep(10000);

                System.out.println("Report Passed");
            }
        }
    }

    @After
    public void teardown() {
        driver.close();
        //System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer my code is running when the window is in focus and opens the CSV file but when i move to other window and the script runs in the background at that time CSV file is not opened.

Answer (score 0):

I see you've used Robot with pressing Enter, and of course it'll work on the window which has the focus!

So once you moves out, the enters are fired on the newly focused window.

Answer (score 0):

The pop up window was browser pop which was not handled by robot keys, so i used third party app "auto it" but it has limitation only used for windows operating system , not supported by unix or linux .